# How do I insert HTML just before the body closing tag?

Tags: 7, hooks

I am looking for the best way to insert arbitrary HTML content into a page before the closing body tag, similar to the way `drupal_add_js()` adds JavaScript to the bottom of a page.

I am coming from a Wordpress background, and in Wordpress this could be accomplished by using the `wp_footer()` hook.

I have looked into using `hook_page_alter()`, but I was wondering if this was the correct way to do this or if there is a better way of accomplishing this task.

Comment: Similar questions like this one pops up every now and then, and I always wonder _why_, is it necessary to "insert HTML just before the body tag". It seems to me like you're approaching whatever you are doing in the wrong way?

Comment: I can't speak for why others want to do it, but in my case I am adding Underscore JS templates to the page for blocks that require them. However, multiple blocks may utilize one template so I wanted to add all templates to the bottom of the page so that I could easily see if they had been loaded or not. For me it is basically an aesthetics / convenience thing.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being slow, but that doesn't make sense to me? With the cache/aggregation/etc benefits of [#attached](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#attached), that can be used on more than forms, I still don't understand the why.

Comment: I was not aware of the versatility of #attached, so thank you for introducing it to me. However in my case I am writing the contents of those template files to the page (not just linking to the files), so correct me if I am wrong but I don't think the cache/aggregation benefits of #attached matter in this case because the actual page caching will take care of it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The equivalent of [hook_footer()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_footer/6) that was used in Drupal 6 is to implement [hook_page_build()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_page_build/7), and alter the content of `$page['page_bottom']`, using code similar to the following one:

```
function mymodule_page_build(&$page) {
  $page['page_bottom']['devel'] = array(
    '#weight' => 25, 
    '#markup' => '<div style="clear:both;">' . devel_query_table() . '</div>',
  );
}
```

The content of `$page['page_bottom']` is output from [html.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--html.tpl.php/7), using the following code:

```
  <?php print $page_top; ?>
  <?php print $page; ?>
  <?php print $page_bottom; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The value of `$page_bottom` is initialized from [template_process_html()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_process_html/7) using the following code:

```
  // Render page_top and page_bottom into top level variables.
  $variables['page_top'] = drupal_render($variables['page']['page_top']);
  $variables['page_bottom'] = drupal_render($variables['page']['page_bottom']);
  // Place the rendered HTML for the page body into a top level variable.
  $variables['page'] = $variables['page']['#children'];
  $variables['page_bottom'] .= drupal_get_js('footer');
```

The difference between [hook_page_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7) and `hook_page_build()` is that `hook_page_alter()` is executed after `hook_page_build()` and should be used to alter, or remove content added by another module, while `hook_page_build()` should be used to add new content to the page.

Comment: Thank you for going above and beyond with this answer. This is very helpful.